# Como capturar a renderização do status (pending) para svg não carregados na tela?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

Tenho um avatar que se monta com arquivos SVG, o problema é que ele fica desmontado antes do status 200. Como eu poderia capturar o status (pending) para só depois que ele carregar mostrar o avatar?

**Exemplo de onde é renderizado o cabelo do avatar na view da HTML:**

```
 <!-- cabelo -->
<div class="hair" ng-if="avatarUser.hair != null" ng-class="avatarUser.hair.model">
   <div class="hair-color">
      <div ng-bind-html="resultSVG.hair"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**O serviço que converte a URL em conteúdo HTML do avatar:**

```
this.convertAvatar = function(url_svg, $scope, type) {

    var request = $http({
         method: "get",
         url: url_svg
    });
    var svg = request.then( _handleSuccess, _handleFail );
        svg.then(function(result){
            $scope.resultSVG[type] = $sce.trustAsHtml(result);
        });

 };

function _handleFail(response) {
    verifyFail(response);
    loadingOff('');
}

function _handleSuccess(response) {

    if($http.pendingRequests.length === 0){
        loadingOff('');
    }
     return response.data;
}
```

**O que é para ler do avatar... seria estes pending...**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema colocando uma variável de verificação do total lido:

```
 this.convertAvatar = function(url_svg, $scope, type) {

     var request = $http({
                      method: "get",
                      url: url_svg
                   });
     var svg = request.then(_handleSuccess, _handleFail);
         svg.then(function (result) {
                    $scope.total_svg_ready++;
                    $scope.resultSVG[type] = $sce.trustAsHtml(result);
                    if ($scope.total_itens_avatar == $scope.total_svg_ready) {
                         $scope.IsLoadingSvg = false;
                    }
                });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um filter nas imagens exemplo
deixe todas display: none

```js
var lengthUnloadImg = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img")).filter(function(a){ return a.complete != true }).length

  while(lengthUnloadImg > 0){
    setTimeOut(function(){
      lengthUnloadImg = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img")).filter(function(a){ return a.complete != true }).length
    }, 1000);
  }
```